# How can I shorten the URL via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My page will open as `https://example.com/profile/account.php?act=reviews&user=1`. But it's too long. Can I shorten it to `https://example.com/profile/1/reviews` using `.htaccess`? Sample codes are not available. But this error is working.

Approximate code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /profile/account.php?act=reviews&user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work. What exactly is happening when you request `https://example.com/profile/1/reviews`? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What do you mean by "Sample codes are not available" and "But this error is working"? And why "Approximate code"? Is that not your _actual code_?

Comment: I did it in the code https://example.com/profile/account.php?act=articles&user=1 and it works as https://example.com/profile/1/articles. But if I set it to https://example.com/profile/account.php?act=reviews&user=1 without opening https://example.com/profile/1/reviews https://example.com/profile/account.php?act=articles&user=1 page